# Replace text with CSS for woocommerce LOGIN page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to replace a text with css, im using this code but not working...

https://monettia.com/mi-cuenta/

"Register" text

```
div.u-column2.col-2 h2{
 visibility:hidden;
}
div.u-column2.col-2 h2{
 content: 'new text';
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this, i hope it will work. It is only idea that the work can be done in this way

```
div.u-column2.col-2 h2{
 position: relative;
}
div.u-column2.col-2 h2:after{
    visibility: visible;
    content: 'new text';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
}
```